# Keycloak registration page is not storing new register user role in LDAP

Tags: keycloak, wildfly-10

I am using keycloak 1.9.3-Final and ApacheDS 2.0.0 as my "User Federation" provider. The goal is to store newly registered users' details (this details include a default role) into both the ApacheDS and keycloak DB. I created a "user" role at a relam level and assign this to the "Realm Default Role" as a default role for every new user; and, in the "User Federation Mappers", I created "myRoleMapper" which sets the "LDAP Roles DN" to ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com

The result is that, I am able to see new registered users details store in both ApacheDS and keycloak DB. However, the "user" role is never associated/stored for the users in the "user" role entry in ApacheDS. Consequently, when the user login I do get a "Forbidden" page as no role is associate to the user. Suprisingly, I am able to sync roles between keycloak and ApacheDS using either the "Sync LDAP Roles To Keycloak" or "Sync Keycloak Roles To LDAP" feature. So, it does appear that the communication between the keycloak server and ApacheDS are fine. However, my role mapping isn't assocaited to the user. Can anyone point me to something I need to do/configure in order to get new registered users details and role added into the ApacheDS from keycloak registration page?

Here is an image of my mappper in keycloak.

[image]

Here is my default user role:

[image]

Here is my ApacheDS schema

```
dn: uid=qq,ou=people,dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: top
cn: qq
sn: qq
mail: qq@ie.com
uid: qq
userpassword:: e1NTSEF9dXl4SEZxTXlQTFJSK0hCN2w2eTM0SXI0ZUo1T3M2TVJOZzB3Tnc9P
 Q==

dn: cn=offline_access,ou=people,dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectclass: groupOfNames
objectclass: top
cn: offline_access
member: cn=empty-membership-placeholder

dn: uid=vv,ou=people,dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: top
cn: vv
sn: vv
mail: vv@ew.ee
uid: vv
userpassword:: e1NTSEF9R3BQaUVUL1c1MTVDZHJROHplRWw2ZlYvYXBtWUpFWk12UDJPeUE9P
 Q==

dn: cn=admin,ou=people,dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectclass: groupOfNames
objectclass: top
cn: admin
member: cn=empty-membership-placeholder

dn: ou=peopleroles,ou=people,dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: peopleroles

dn: ou=people,dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: people

dn: ou=peoplegroups,ou=people,dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: peoplegroup
ou: peoplegroups

dn: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: top
cn: test
sn: test user
uid: testuser

dn: dc=myCompany,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: domain
dc: myCompany
```